# I want to convert the char matrix into numbers in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

I want to convert the string into numbers for example `x=[abacaaaabb]` I want to assign values `a=1 b=2 and c=-1` and store in new matrix  `x=[1 2 1 -1....}`

Answer (score 7):

You can create a mapping:

```
map = zeros(1,256);
map('abc') = [1, 2, -1];
```

Then you can just index it with your input:

```
x = 'abacaaaabb';
mx = map(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way (unless your mapping really does have to be arbitrary like in your example):

```
x=['abacaaaabb'];
```

num = x - 96

results in

```
num =

     1     2     1     3     1     1     1     1     2     2
```

Comment: Read the question carefully.